# Update WPF Image Control Programmatically from Webcam Input

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

I am capturing image frames from a webcam but when I set them to WPF's Image control it appears blank.

The library I am using returns a Bitmap so I convert it to a BitmapImage and then set the source of my Image control to the BitmapImage through Dispatcher:

```
void OnImageCaptured(Touchless.Vision.Contracts.IFrameSource frameSource, Touchless.Vision.Contracts.Frame frame, double fps)
    {
        image = frame.Image; // This is a class variable of type System.Drawing.Bitmap 
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(UpdatePicture));
    }

    private void UpdatePicture()
    {
        imageControl.Source = null;
        imageControl.Source = BitmapToBitmapImage(image);
    }

    private BitmapImage BitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();
            return bi;
        }
    }
```

The XAML declaration on my Image control is about as generic as can be:

```
<Image x:Name="imageControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="94,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Nothing is showing up in the Image control - there are no run-time errors.  What am I doing wrong?
Thank you so very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` when you're creating the BitmapImage. Without that, the bitmap is loaded lazily, and the stream will be closed by the time the UI gets around to asking for it. Microsoft notes this in the documentation for [BitmapImage.CacheOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing the image to a temporary MemoryStream you could also directly convert from `Bitmap` to `BitmapSource` by calling [`Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx):

```
private void UpdatePicture()
{
    imageControl.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        image.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```